# What sort of thesis can be proven with factor analysis?

Tags: statistics

I am learning (or atleast trying to) factor analysis and I don't really understand what theories / thesis's can be proved with it. It is supposed to show the hidden connection (latents) between different varaibles in a dataset, though what can be proven (or disproven with that)

To make things clear, consider the following dataset:
http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/personality.sav

The description is `a set of responses from a personality questionnaire.`
(the original website: http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/page16/page16.html )

You have qualities such as: `orignal`, `helpful`, `reserved`, `reliable`, `tense` (and a lot more).

What sort of thesis can be made about this dataset which is proven or disproven with factor analysis ?

**note:** This is (an obvious) rephrase of the original question.